# Java mkdirs with / (slash) in foldername

Tags: java, slash, mkdirs

I have a problem with java and `mkdirs`.

I would like to create a folder with / in its name like:
`C:\Sun/Moon\`

```
String pfad = projektnummer;
if (!kunde.isEmpty()) {
    pfad = pfad + " " + kunde;
}
if (!projektname.isEmpty()) {
    pfad = pfad + " - " + projektname;
}
File ziel = new File("P://" + pfad)
ziel.mkdirs();
```

The content of kunde can be something like `Microsaft/Apple`.

At the moment I get a `C:\Microsaft\Apple` and not `C:\Microsoft/Apple\`.

Comment: A slash in filenames is not allowed!!

Comment: Slash are note allowed in file/dirnames. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: `"/"` are not allowed in diretory names on Windows OS. It is a constraint enforced by operating system, there is nothing that you can do in Java to circumvent it. `"/"` means traversing to the child directory, and you cannot have it in dir name.

Comment: Windows -.-*
This just happens when you develop under Linux and then try it under Windows :D
Thx, that was the solution

Comment: While the linked question asks about Python, the answer is the same.  You can't do it.

Comment: Exactly. That's why using "File.separator" in your Java code is always a good idea. It is your JVM that will put "/" under Unix-based OS or "\" under Windows.

Comment: @Iralution - Read the document again.  It says 1) "/" is special, and 2) it is *silently* converted to a "\".  Of course, you could use a Unicode *homoglyph* for "/" ... if one existed ... but then that is not a real forward-slash character at all.

Comment: @Iralution - a homoglyph for forward-slash does exist - 0x2044

Comment: Yeah correct, it's the divison character. Anyway, I would not recommend to use it.